# WP Custom Post Type not showing in GoDaddy admin bar but does on other hosts and locally

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, shared-hosting, wp-admin

I've developed and staged a site with a custom post type using the same method used on countless other WP builds. When I've uploaded it to the client's GoDaddy Managed WP hosting however, the post type isn't showing in the admin menu.

It did show in my local dev and on another host I use for live staging.

The front-end still displays all the information contained in these posts, the 'Simple Custom Post Order' plugin I've used still shows the CPT as an option to allow ordering in its settings. I've tried installing the Custom Post Type UI plugin but the slug is already taken when I try to recreate so it all seems to be suggesting that the CPT is registered and being used but for some reason it won't show in the admin bar.

There was a previous site on the hosting but I used a Duplicator Pro package and deleted all the WP core files/folders so none of the previous site db/files are still in existence.

GoDaddy have reinstalled the whole account(?) and say they can't look into fixing the error because I didn't use a plugin to create it (without extra payment). It feels like it must be something fairly straightforward but I'm out of options.

The function used to create it is as follows:

```
function create_people_posttype(){
    $args = array(
        'label' => 'people',
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => __('People'),
            'singular_name' => __('People'),
            'add_new' => __('Add New'),
            'add_new_item' => __('Add New People'),
            'edit_item' => __('Edit People'),
            'new_item' => __('New People'),
            'view_item' => __('View People'),
            'search_items' => __('Search People'),
            'not_found' => __('No People found'),
            'not_found_in_trash' => __('No People found in trash'),
            'all_items' => __('All People'),
            'archives' => __('People Archives'),
            'insert_into_item' => __('Insert into People'),
            'uploaded_to_this_item' => __('Uploaded to this People'),
            'featured_image' => __('People Image'),
            'set_featured_image' => __('Set People Image'),
            'remove_featured_image' => __('Remove People Image'),
            'use_featured_image' => __('Use People Image'),
            'menu_name' => __('People')
        ),
        'description' => __('Post type to contain content for People.'),
        'public' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'show_in_admin_bar' => true,
        'menu_position' => 15,
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-groups', // https://developer.wordpress.org/resource/dashicons/
        'supports' => array('title','editor','author','thumbnail','excerpt','trackbacks','comments','revisions','page-attributes'),
        'has_archive' => true,
        'rewrite' => array('slug'=>'people','with_front'=>false),
        'capabilities' => array(
            'edit_post'          => 'update_core',
            'read_post'          => 'update_core',
            'delete_post'        => 'update_core',
            'edit_posts'         => 'update_core',
            'edit_others_posts'  => 'update_core',
            'delete_posts'       => 'update_core',
            'publish_posts'      => 'update_core',
            'read_private_posts' => 'update_core'
        ),
    );
    register_post_type('people',$args);
}
function create_people_taxonomy() {

    register_taxonomy(
            'people-category',
            'people',
            array(
                    'label' => __( 'Category' ),
                    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'people-cat' ),
                    'hierarchical' => true,
                    'taxonomies' => array('post_tag'),
            )
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'create_people_taxonomy' );

add_action('init','create_people_posttype',0);
```

I've include all the show_in options as well as the kitchen sink.

Any thoughts and guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: is there anything in debug log and or the go daddy apache / php error logs?  Are you running the same version of php in both environments?

Comment: Thanks @Cameron, no WP logs and can't access them on GoDaddy managed hosting, apparently. Local PHP is 7.4.8, staging is 7.4.22 and goDaddy is 7.3. Would those version differences have much of an affect?

Comment: Some kind of weird caching issue?

Comment: yup, my bet is on caching.

Comment: Thanks. Any thoughts on how best to relieve it? GoDaddy's cache purge plugin didn't clear it and I've not got any other caching plugins installed.

Comment: is your shared host running out of memory?  usually in godaddy you can check error_logs for php and apache in their version of cpanel.  turn on WPDEBUG so it writes the debuglog to file and check permissions on your files.